# Nodebuffer is not supported by this platform

Tags: reactjs, shapefile

My code is running into a Nodebuffer that is not supported by this platform error.

Full error message:

```
node buffer is not supported by this platform in reacts, type of file reader. the result is ArrayBuffer(55826922)
```

Code:

```js
import * as shp from 'shpjs'

shp(fileReader.result) // generate this error
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) npm install -S buffer
2) // vue.config.js
const { ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        buffer: require.resolve('buffer/'),
      },
    },
    plugins: [
      new ProvidePlugin({
        Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).